# How to return output from lambda function to web-front on search using API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying set up a search bar on my web-front that will allow the user to search for data in my dynamodb table using the key and then returns the results to the website.

i tried to create an API POST function that that gives the value of the key that is being searched for to the lambda function. the resultant data from the lambda function is then presented on the web front via API GET.

here is the relevant java script and html code and the relevant code from the lambda function.

thank you very very much to those who chose to help i greatly appreciate it

html

```
<table id='table' style="width:50%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>pKey</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myunipolapi">
                </tbody>
            </table>

        <form>
            <textarea id="srch" placeholder="Search Data"></textarea>
        </form>
        <div>
            <button id='searchButton'>Search</button>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript ajax GET

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: API_URL,

                    success: function(data){
                        $('#myunipolapi').html('');

                        data.Items.forEach(function(HeartbeatItem){
                            $('#myunipolapi').append(
                                       '<tr id="TT"><td id="TT">' + HeartbeatItem.pKey + '</td><td id="TT">' + HeartbeatItem.message + '</td><td id="TT">' + HeartbeatItem.password + '</td></tr>' 
                            );
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
```

Javascript ajax POST

```
$('#searchButton').on('click',function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: API_URL,
                    data: JSON.stringify({"search": $('#srch').val()}),
                    contentType: "application/json",

                    success: function(data){
                          $('#TT').load('#myunipolapi');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Lambda

```
console.log('starting function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {

    console.log(event); 

 var queryParams = {
        TableName: 'Heartbeat',
        Key: {
            "pKey": event.search
        }
    }; 

    docClient.get(queryParams, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

API

```
{
    "message": $input.json('$.message'),
    "password": $input.json('$.password'),
    "pKey": $input.json('$.pKey'),
    "search": $input.json('$.search')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that in your lambda:

```
 const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: 'eu-west-2'});
 const params = {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ":key": {
     S: event.search
    }
  }, 
  KeyConditionExpression: "pKey = :key", 
  TableName: "Heartbeat"
 };
 dynamodb.query(params, (err, data) => {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

More info about NodeJS AWS-SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work thank you any way though ... i think maybe the problem might lie in the javascript at the webfront or maybe how the data is sent to the lambda function because i have two buttons using the same format except different inputs will add a copy of the code i have in API if it is at all help full.